# Python inside Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

Good afternoon, guys.

I have a python project which brings me the Continent of a Country. It's a web scrapping in wikipedia site. How can I apply this as a new column in Power BI, turning the country (in example below, the "United_States") into a parameter which gonna be the countries of my Power BI Report (the countries are in the 1st column of my BI Report.)?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_United_States"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

continent = soup.select_one("th:-soup-contains(Continent) + td").text
print(continent)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Power BI, you should use the `Web.Contents` function to scrape the web page.
Here's a simple query that gets the html from the wikipedia page and parses it:
`let
Source = Web.Contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_United_States"),
Data = Json.Document(Source)
in
Data`

You can then use Power BI's `Parsed HTML` feature to parse the HTML and create a data set.
If you want to use Python to do this, you should use the `pandas` library to load the data into a DataFrame and then use the `to_csv()` function to write the data to a CSV file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_United_States"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
continent = soup.select_one("th:-soup-contains(Continent) + td").text
print(continent)
df = pd.DataFrame([continent])
df.to_csv("continent.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

If you want to do this in R, you should use the `rvest` library to parse the HTML and then use the `readr` library to read the data into a data frame.

```
library(rvest)
library(readr)
url &lt;- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_United_States"
html &lt;- read_html(url)
continent &lt;- html_nodes(html, "th:-soup-contains(Continent) + td") %&gt;% html_text()
df &lt;- data.frame(continent)
write_csv(df, "continent.csv")
```

Comment: Amirreza, thanks for your reply. This would be perfect if the Python Project already had all continents, but in my case, i would need make the country in the url as a parameter. In my original csv in Power BI, i've almost 200 countries in the 1st column. So, in the power bi, i would use this countries for fill the parameter and bring me the Continent

Comment: i added new answer. if its fine to you please green tick it otherwise tell me the prob. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the continent of any country with the following code:

```
#load libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#country name
country_name = "United States"

#build url
url_start = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
url_country = country_name.replace(" ", "_")
url = url_start + url_country

#get HTML
r = requests.get(url)

#parse HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

#get continent
continent = soup.select_one("th:contains(Continent) + td").text

#print continent
print(continent)

#save to csv
df = pd.DataFrame([continent], columns = ["continent"])
df.to_csv("continent.csv", index = False, header = False)
```